# When not to do maximum compression in png?

Tags: graphics, compression, png

**Intro**
When saving png images through GIMP, I've always used level 9 (maximum) compression, as I knew that it's lossless. Now I've to specify compression level when saving png format image through GD extension of PHP.

**Question**
Is there any case when I shouldn't compress PNG to maximum level? Like any compatibility issues? If there's no problem then why to ask user; why not automatically compress to max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each level of PNG compression requires significantly more memory and processing power to compress (and decompress to a lesser degree).

There is a rapid tailoff in the compression gains from each level, however, so choose one that balances the webserver resources available for compression with your need to reduce bandwith.